# Max size of an email body

Tags: java

I'm using javamail to send out a potentially large HTML report. It's preferable to inline the report in the message body but sometimes the report will need to be zipped and attached.
Recipients can be using any mail client. Given that the mail client is not fixed, I'm looking for feedback as to what will be a sensible threshold for the email body, (crossing which the report will be zipped and attached)

Comment: From what I understand, the limit is usually the same. That is, if your e-mail provider only allows mail up to 20 megabytes, it doesn't matter if those 20 megabytes are in the message body or in an attachment - it is still not allowed.

Comment: Not sure why you could not find this easy to find link  https://www.outlook-apps.com/maximum-email-size/

Comment: Usually you shouldn't form mail messages more than few MBs in size because your reports will be delivered through a chain of mail hosts, some of which could be out of your control and impose their own limits. Please remember, that a zip being attached into a message, is stored with Base64 encoding usually, so its size is increased by 8/6.